# protected access modifier meaning of derived

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    class TestA
    {
        protected string protectedStringA;
    }

    class TestB : TestA
    {
        string StringTestB()
        {
            return protectedStringA;
        }
    }

    class TestC : TestB
    {
        string StringTestC()
        {
            return protectedStringA;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


    }
}
```

As per [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) link the definition of **protected** is "The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or **in a class that is derived from that class**". Here the Class TestC is not derived from TestA. But the protectedStringA is still accessible. What is the exact meaning of **class that is derived from that class**?

Comment: TestC is derived from TestB which is derived from TestA, TestC is a TestA.

Answer (score 2):

Since `B` inherits `A's` (public and protected) members, `C` inherits all of them from `B`. That's the point of inheritance.

> What is the exact meaning of class that is derived from that class?

It means a derived class can access protected members of it's base class. In this case `C` is actualy inheriting from `A` indirectly.So it has access to all `public` and `protected` members of it's base classes.

Comment: Like wise, the **protected** member can be accessed by any derived classes in the chain! This is almost like having an access level of **internal**.

Comment: @JohnSmith No, it isn't. The `internal` access modifier grants access to any file in the same assembly. I needn't be in the same assembly to derive from a `public` class, nor do I need to derive from a class to be in the same assembly.

Comment: Like wise, the **protected** member can be accessed by any derived classes in the chain! This is almost like having an access level of **internal**. Give me one example where this **protected** method can't be accessed by inherited Classes  in that inheritance chain.

Comment: There isn't one. There are plenty of `internal` members which can't be accessed by inherited classes in the inheritance chain, however, e.g. all of them that are defined in a separate assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Even though TestC is not directly derived from TestA, it is indirectly because TestB inherits TestA. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put it on other words:

"Any class can access any protected members of its ancestors".

If `TypeA` is an ancestor of `TypeB` and `TypeB` is an ancestor of `TypeC`, than `TypeA` is an ancestor of `TypeC`.